# Does a single Tesla K80 look like one GPU or two in Windows 10?

Tags: gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, dual-gpu

Does a Tesla K80 appear as 1 GPU or 2 in Windows 10 with standard NVidia drivers.  It is CUDA Compute Level 3.5.  That is [good enough for TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu).  It is good enough for Torch and other packages?  If it comes up as 2 12GB GPUs rather than 1 24GB GPU, will the usual packages like TF and Torch use both GPUs (memory and cores) fully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single K80 card should show up as two devices. 
"Good enough" is a relative term. Many researchers opt for the cheaper GTX (or now RTX) series cards over K-series or Quadros for the types of workloads you want to tackle.

Paralleling the computation is what you are after to use multiple devices with the same problem. You can get good speedup through paralleling the computation with the types of neural networks used in deep learning.

This blog post is a very good read:
http://timdettmers.com/2018/11/05/which-gpu-for-deep-learning/

As a benchmark the company Lambda labs sells turnkey GPU deep learning machines with three different cards: GTX 1080 ti, RTX 2080 ti, and Titan V cards.

Comment: It sells on Amazon for $600 and has 24GB of RAM.  I am doing a machine translation challenge (OpenCLIR19) where I feel the need for more RAM vs more speed, so my gut says it's a good bet.  The equivalent amount of RAM in a 2080ti would cost me $2400, which is too big a bet for me.